# How to Read FBX data at Unity Runtime

Tags: unity-game-engine, fbx

I'm trying to read FBX data like SkinMeshRenderer in unity Runtime don't know how to do that I'm confused at loading FBX as the game object

now the problem is I can't create a prefab out of FBX b/c it can be loaded from web just need to read its skinMeshRenderer or mesh or material

if you know any solution please share it

Comment: I figure out the solution I'm Importing it as GameObject and then reading the data.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

actually it was simple not that hard loading the FBX as game Object and then it's made easy to read the data

the above code is just for testing don't look at the loop :P

Comment: now that can also happen just wanted to see how to access FBX data inside the unity Downloading from the Web is another step.